# End user tool for generating a regular expression

Tags: .net, regex, nlp

We have a SaaS application requirement to allow a user responsible for building a CMS site to define up to 10 custom fields in a form. 
As part of this field definition we want to add a field validation option which we will store (and apply at runtime) as a reg-ex.

Are there any tools, code samples or similar that offer a wizard style front end for building a reg-ex. We are looking to embed a control or code into our .NET site that will generate the reg-ex from (pseudo) user friendly terms (close to natural language if possible).

e.g.
Field 1 = (5 alphanumerics) followed-by (1 to 3 numerics) followed by "-" followed by 1 alpha

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any tools that you can embed into your application.  RegexBuddy, which I developed, does provide a COM interface and a command line interface that allows your application to send a regular expression to RegexBuddy, and receive the modified regular expression back from RegexBuddy.  [RegexBuddy's web site](http://www.regexbuddy.com/integration.html) has more details.

RegexBuddy shows an English language analysis of the regular expression, and provides an "Insert Token" menu to easily build up a regular expression without remembering the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I really like regexbuddy
http://www.regexbuddy.com/

expresso is really good to, and will generate c# code
http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

both will show you a "pseudo" representation of the regex

Comment: Can I embed this in my application?

Comment: expresso is written entirely in .net, so you *could* add a reference to their assemblies and use their controls and such.... but i am pretty sure they wouldn't like that... divo provided the code project for the older expresso, that may be of some use.

Answer (score 0):

Expresso:

> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/expresso.aspx

There is also an advanced (commercial) version (http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)